# How to make a spinner in React Native? I want to rotate box via PanResponder

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rotation, components, panresponder

I am trying to use PanResponder in react native in order to rotate a box at its center. This is my code so far:

```
class Spinner extends React.Component {

 pan = new Animated.ValueXY();
 panResponder = PanResponder.create({
   onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
   onPanResponderGrant: () => {
    this.pan.setOffset({
      x: this.pan.x._value,
      y: this.pan.y._value
    });
   },
   onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
    null,
    { dx: this.pan.x, dy: this.pan.y }
   ]),
   onPanResponderRelease: () => {
    this.pan.flattenOffset();
   }

 });


 render() {

  const RotateValue = "10deg"

  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width:100,
          height:300,
          transform:[{ rotate: RotateValue }]
        }}
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
       <View style={styles.box} />
      </Animated.View>
    </View>

  )
}
```

}

'''

In this const RotateValue, I am trying to use this.pan.x and this.pan.y in order to covert to a value of degrees. I put "10deg" to demonstrate that it would rotate 10 degrees. But I am lost in how to accomplish what I am setting out to do.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is something called interpolation.
you can find more about it here: https://animationbook.codedaily.io/interpolate/#:~:text=The%20interpolate%20function%20allows%20animated,interpolate%20from%20other%20interpolate%20values.&text=What%20this%20is%20doing%20is,we%20are%20interpolating%20the%20opacity.

```
const RotateValue = this.pan.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 360],
    outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
});
```

I know that it is not the most accurate or best answer but I hope you will find this helpful somehow.

Comment: Thank you. That's definitely brought me a lot closer to what I''m trying to do! Since it's using "this.pan.x" for interpolation, it rotates when I slide my cursor from left to right (aka along the x axis of the screen. Do you know of a way to combine "this.pan.x" and "this.pan.y" in the interpolation? Again, thank you.

Comment: It all depends on how you want the spinner to act.  You can for example interpolate pan.x  to rotateX and pan.y to rotateY.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is simply have my finger rotate the spinner around its center and have it follow my finger. In other words, if my finger touched the spinner object and went around its axis in a circle, the spinner would follow my finger around.   I worked on it a little and I used "Animated.add(this.pan.x, this.pan.y).interpolate" and it works mostly for the top right quadrant of the screen. So I'm at another crossroads again.